# nth word of String (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

What's the simplest way to get the nth word of a String in Kotlin?  I've written some code that does it (although it would currently include punctuation as part of a word), but I think there must be a much simpler way.

Comment: You forgot to add the code to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the test I just printed out all elements, you can see that punctuations have been filtered out. The `words` is a list of string, I think you know how to get the nth element from it:

```
@Test
fun `extract word`() {
    val input = "However, the sentence, which I am writing ... now, has words...."
    val words = input.split("[.,!;\"\\s]+".toRegex())
    words.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Outputs:

```
However
the
sentence
which
I
am
writing
now
has
words
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start with this code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val sentence = "Hello, green world!"
    val words = sentence.split("[,.!?\\s]+".toRegex())
    val thirdWord = words[2]

    println(words)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val n = 4   // 4th word
    val str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

    val word = str.split(" ")[n-1]
    println(word)   // fox
}
```